# New Star Wars Battlefront tag problem

Tags: discussion, tags

What should be done about tagging for the new Star Wars Battlefront? It has the exact same name as the original Star Wars Battlefront.

Should the original be retagged as [star-wars-battlefront-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-1) or should the new one be tagged as [battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefront-2015)? Any other possibilities here?

Either way, I think the [star-wars-battlefront](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront) tag should be put to sleep because now it refers to two games and will therefore cause confusion.

Comment: Maybe we can call it `star-wars-battlefront-15` (24 characters)?

Comment: @angussidney That would be very confusing for new users. As if there were 14 before it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think using `sw` as the prefix works best.

For example, SWTOR is commonly used to refer to the Star Wars: The Old Republic game.

Keeping that in mind, we can do the following:

- I:  [sw-battlefront-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-1)
- II: [sw-battlefront-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-2)
- 2015: [sw-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-2015)

Comment: I think the "15" is a little ambiguous. It should be "2015" if possible.

Comment: Then doing sw-battlefront-2015 works as well :)

Comment: I used sw-battlefront-2015 for my questions. Thanks!

Comment: Oh boy these tags need text explaining which game they are for because I didn't even know that there was more than one Star Wars Battlefront game until I read this.